# Pinter' s Set Theory Problem

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Given functions $g,h: A \rightarrow B$ and a set C that contains at least two elements, with $f \circ g = f \circ h$ for all $f:B \rightarrow C$. Prove that $g = h$.

My logic is to take C = B and h(x) =x for all x in particular and the result follows immediately. But, I don't see the use of the condition on C. 
Please somebody help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be distinct elements of $C$. If $g(a)\neq h(a)$ for some $a\in A$, then define $f:B\rightarrow C$ by $f(g(a))=x$ and $f(b)=y$ for all $b\neq g(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition on C ensures, that the functions f are not one and the same constant function.

In addition it seems to me that you got the question somehow wrong.
Instead of a proof, I want to give you some intuition.

Think of g and h for example as temperature measurements at different times of a day, i. e. a variable quantity.
f is "what you can do" with the temperature measurements.